# List of IdentityUsers in SQL database returns different results depending on the logged in user in blazor server-side application

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a model called ForumPost for storing the required values to display a forum post created by an `IdentityUser`.

```
type public class ForumPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20000)]
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public bool IsEdited { get; set; } = false;

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsEditied { get; set; } = false;

    public List<IdentityUser> UpvotedList { get; set; } = new List<IdentityUser>();

    public List<IdentityUser> DownvotedList { get; set; } = new List<IdentityUser>();

    [MaxLength(450)]
    public string IdentityUserId { get; set; }//Required forigenkey

    public IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }//Required reference to object
}
```

This model also contains two lists of `IdentityUsers` for keeping track of upvotes and downvotes. In a service called `ForumPostService`, I have methods for adding and removing users to and from these lists on a specific instance of a `ForumPost` in the database.

I also have implemented scaffolded identity into my project, and have it set up with one seeded user for testing purposes.

The user seed:

```
private static async Task CreateAdminUserAsync(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
        string email = "email@email.com";
        string password = "Password123$";

        if (!await userManager.Users.AnyAsync(u => u.Email == email))
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = email, Email = email, EmailConfirmed = true };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
        }
}
```

The ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }

    public DbSet<CalendarEvent> CalendarEvent { get; set; } = default!;

    public DbSet<ForumPost> ForumPost { get; set; } = default!;

    public DbSet<ForumPostComment> ForumPostComment { get; set; } = default!;

}
```

A `ForumPost` is displayed using several Razor components called from within Razor pages in my app.

My issue starts when I try to vote on a post and view the votes on a different account that I registered. The only votes that seem to carry over and display for everyone is the votes made by the seeded user, and votes made by registered users only appear for that registered user.

I have tried to using `Console.WriteLine()` to track the value of the `UpvotedList` and `DownvotedList` across the entire process, and from the moment that the `ForumPost` is retrieved, the lists only contains the votes from the seeded user, and the currently logged in registered user.

I have no idea what could be causing this inconsistency in the lists when I try to retrieve the same `ForumPost` object from the different accounts.

Comment: What is the DbContext configuration for this model?

Comment: @Serhii I've updated the question with the code from the ApplicationDbContext file.

Comment: It's actually looks like you have no property for referencing upwoted/downvoted users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many

Comment: @Serhii , so I should add a new model to my application that contains a reference to a user and a post, and instead fill the lists on my ForumPost with instances of those objects?

Comment: Actually yes. For more understanding you can have a look in your database and look at created tables structure. You will see how it behaves when you try to save there more then 1 vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the issue thanks to help from Serhii in the comments.

The problem that I was having was due to the fact that I was trying to directly store a list of `IdentityUser` objects, and not using another model class to store a reference to both the `IdentityUser` and the `ForumPost` that the logged in user was voting on.

I solved this by implementing a model class with the appropriate references, and storing it in the lists instead:

```
public class ForumVote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsUpvote { get; set; } = true;

    [MaxLength(450)]
    public string IdentityUserId { get; set; }//Required forigenkey

    public IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }//Required reference to object

    public int ForumPostId { get; set; }//Required forigenkey

    public ForumPost ForumPost { get; set; }//Required reference to object
```

The `ForumPost` class:

```
public class ForumPost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20000)]
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public bool IsEdited { get; set; } = false;

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsEditied { get; set; } = false;

    public List<ForumVote> ForumVoteList { get; set; } = new List<ForumVote>();

    [MaxLength(450)]
    public string IdentityUserId { get; set; }//Required forigenkey

    public IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }//Required reference to object
```